# Is it possible to change the LED notification color on Galaxy S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notification-led

I want to be able to select which colors show up for different notifications such as sms email facebook and phone calls.  I know the led for the s3 is capable of showing multiple colors but don't know if these are changeable, I've seen it on other phones tho (my old bb curve) I figured android has something similar.

thanks,

Comment: Galaxy S3 has LEDs?

Comment: Heck yeah it does! One of the biggest upgrades in coming from the Galaxy S Captivate!

Answer (score 5):

If you have a US Galaxy S3, all LED programs have issues with the colors (Handcent, GoSMS, etc) except LightFlow.  If you select Green, it will be Blue, etc.  LightFlow works flawlessly.  The problme I have with LightFlow is the battery would drain faster with the app installed.  I ran a test where I left the phone idle for 55 mins (no screen on, no led flashing, no gps, txt, phone..) and battery drainage was 8-10%.  I uninstalled the app, and did the same test and battery drainage was only 4%.  For now (until GoSMS supports LED for the US S3), I'm just using the built in S3 Led Notification option (under system settings).  It works, you just can't change the colors.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the app in question. Handcent SMS / GoSMS have options for changing the LED colour. As an aside, there's also the ability to configure per-recipient tones, vibrate modes, notification icons and of course LED colours.

If you're looking for an all-in-one app to manage LED notifications for commonly used apps, give [Light Flow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflowlite) a try.

EDIT: Also [Blink](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.blink)

Comment: From comments it seems those both don't work on S3..