# Can you change the colour of the LED light on the Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notification-led

On the top of the phone there's a light that flashes blue when you get a text. Is there an app or setting that can change this so the colour is different for some senders who text you?

Answer (score 2):

There is powerful and full-customizable [GO SMS PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) which lets you set **any LED color** for sms incoming notifications based on sender. Also, it is a mighty alternative for stock sms app and has many useful functions and customizations.

After you installed it, run and tap menu, then **Settings**, and go to **Advanced -> Individual Settings** and add any contact to set individual notification (including LED options) for it.

Comment: How do you install it?

Comment: @Katy Simply follow the link on app name to open its page on google play site. Then click install to receive it in your phone. You should have added your google account in your phone and used google play on the phone at least once. Alternatively, open google play on phone and simply search for "GO SMS PRO".

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27891/is-it-possible-to-change-the-led-notification-color-on-galaxy-s3

Answer (score 1):

There are apps for controlling LEDs: [LED Color Tester](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coolbeans.ledtester), [Light Flow - LED Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflowlite)
Both does officially support Galaxy S3.

Comment: Do those apps can set different colors for different contacts who the user receives SMS from?!! I think Katy has asked for that option.

Answer (score 0):

Many custom ROMS, such as [cm10](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1778217), have built-in support for changing the LED color.